# помогите с ошибкой AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

Код ошибки:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\meles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 417, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\meles\CRAZY_DAYZy\monitoring\main.py", line 37, in on_ready
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

Раньше использовал sqlite3 решил перейти на mysql.connector
не могу понять в чем ошибка) Буду благодарен если поможете с решением !)

```
import nextcord
import os
from nextcord.ext import commands
from config import settings
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'])
#bot.load_extension('jishaku')
bot.remove_command("help")


conn = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="discord"
)
cursor = conn.cursor()


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name VARCHAR(100),
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        warn VARCHAR(100),
        warninfo VARCHAR(100),
        collection_in_mil INT
    )""")
    
    
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id},'1','нет варнов' , 0)")
                conn.commit()
            else:
                pass

    conn.commit()
    print('BOT successfuly connected')
    #await bot.change_presence(activity=nextcord.Game(name="EventBot"))
    #print("Был запущен -", time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', Start_time))




bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Comment: fetchone нужно вызывать от курсора, а не от результата вызова execute. execute ничего не возвращает.

Comment: @insolor вот так ? ```cursor.fetchone(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}") is None:```
TypeError: CMySQLCursor.fetchone() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Двумя отдельными строками: сначала выполняете `cursor.execute` с SQL запросом, потом через `cursor.fetchone()` без параметров получаете строку результата запроса. Посмотрите примеры кода с fetchone.

Comment: @insolor огромное спасибо за подсказку !

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо за помощь @insolor )

````
for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if row is not None:
                print(row)
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                
            else:
                pass```
````